# ¿Cómo puedo usar las FONT-AWESOME en Windows?

Tags: html, css, windows

Hasta el momento solo he usado las font-awesome en páginas web, pero ahora me surge la necesidad de usar esos iconos como fuentes de Windows para utilizarlos en PowerPoint. He visto que en la web de font-awesome se pueden bajar las fuentes TrueType/OpenType, pero cuando las instalo en Windows lo que me aparece es un tipo de letra normal, no los iconos.

A ver si alguien sabe darme la solución. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay dos formas con la tipografía instalada.

De la web http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/ copias y pegas los símbolos, no los códigos sino los símbolos directamente.

Otra opción es ir al menú insertar de powerpoint y en el grupo símbolos hacer click en símbolo y luego seleccionar la tipografía fontawesome y deberían salirte los símbolos para poder seleccionar el que quieras.

Comment: Ok. Perfecto. Conseguido de las dos formas que me has dicho.

Con la primera, selecciona el símbolo como si seleccionaras texto, copia y pega en PowerPoint.

Con la segunda, como se ha explicado, insertando símbolos.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/

pega los codigos de alli teniendo font-awesome seleccionada en powerpoint, deberia funcionar

Comment: No te entiendo. Podrías poner un ejemplo, por favor. No entiendo cuando dices que pegue los códigos. Te refieres al código html en un campo de texto?

Comment: si por ejemplo: [&#xf0f9;]  almenos esta confirmado que funciona asi en photoshop no se si aplique a powerpoint

Comment: Ya te he entendido. No había visto el enlace.

Pero me temo que no funciona. O al menos yo no lo he conseguido. He probado a pegarlo con corchetes y sin corchetes, y a poner el tipo de letra en font-awesome. Y nada.

Muchas gracias. Voy a seguir intentando